# Rest-Assured using Jayways Jsonpath?

Tags: json, rest-assured

I have spent a long time figuring out some JsonPath using Jayways version, my query is the following:

```
$.items[?(@.To[0].Mailbox == 'foobar')]..Body
```

However, this does not work with Rest-Assured, when executing, I am shown the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '[' @ line 1, column 34.
                            $.items[?(@.To[0].Mailbox == 'foobar')]..Body
```

Do I need to rewrite this expression in `GPath` format? if so, what would that look like? or can I somehow have Rest-Assured use this preferred JsonPath expression?

here is a small **[WIP]** piece of code as of now, just trying to get the expression working, then I will fix up the method correctly:

```
public String readInbox(String emailAddress) {
    Response response =  given().log().all().when().get(MESSAGES_ENDPOINT);
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response.asString());
    String emailAddress = jsonPath.getString("$.items[?(@.To[0].Mailbox == 'foobar')]..Body");
    System.out.println(accountVerificationEmailHyperlinkByEmailAddress);
    return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved this by just excluding rest assured completely and using jsonPath on the response body like so:

```
emailBodies = JsonPath.read(given().when().get(MESSAGES_ENDPOINT).getBody().asString(), generatePayLoadForEmailPrefixOf(emailPrefix));
```